# changing page order, imposition, use pdfpages?

Tags: pdfpages, command-line

The commandline tool `pdfjam` provides a wrapper around the `pdfpages` package.

I'm trying to figure out how to do the page ordering or imposition:

A 16-page booklet would print onto 4 sheets of paper:
sheet 1 front: pages 16,1
sheet 1 back: pages 2,15
sheet 2 front: pages 14,3
sheet 2 back: pages 4,13
sheet 3 front: pages 12,5
sheet 3 back: pages 6,11
sheet 4 front: pages 10,7
sheet 4 back: pages 8,9\

This booklet form is for laying all the sheets flat on each other and folding them all at once together.

If we want more pages than can be folded this way (as in a book) we might need to fold each sheet individually, which would give us a page order like:
sheet 1 front: pages 4,1
sheet 1 back: pages 2,3
sheet 2 front: pages 8,5
sheet 2 back: pages 6,7
sheet 3 front: pages 12,9
sheet 3 back: pages 10,11
sheet 4 front: pages 16,13
sheet 4 back: pages 14,15
sheet 5 - 200 or more etc would follow this pattern.

The maintainer of `pdfjam` referred me to the `pdfpages` documentation and I've been looking through https://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf unable to find something promising.

My command looks like `pdfjam --nup 2x1 --landscape myfile.pdf` and in the documentation I can see the `nup` part, and this successfully puts two pages from the source file onto a single sheet in the new pdf that's created, but it doesn't affect the order and I have no idea how to do that.  I don't see anything in the docs about reordering the pages.

Is this something `pdfpages` can do?  How?

Comment: Try `pdfjam --nup 2x1 --landscape myfile.pdf '4,1-3,8,5-7'`. You can use another program to produce the page list. See `pdfjam --help` or the doc of `pdfpages` for more info.

Comment: You can try `pdfbook` and its `--signature` option: `pdfbook --signature=16 myfile.pdf`.

Comment: Option `signature` should do the trick:  `pdfjam --signature 4 --landscape file.pdf`